# How to add iPad support to a PhoneGap application?

Tags: app-store-connect, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have an application - FooApp - built with PhoneGap.

FooApp runs natively on the iPhone platform and it's published on the App Store. FooApp does not, however, run on iPad natively. Instead, it runs with the 1x/2x mode and it's marked as an iPhone-only app on the App Store.

The way FooApp is built - HTML & CSS - it should be able to run on iPad without problems. What setting or config file do I need to change in order for my app to be recognized as a universal app - capable of running on iPhone and iPad - so that I might test it with Testflight as a native iPad app?

Answer (score 0):

In your xcode go to the

> app target -> general tab -> deployment info -> device

and then select

> universal

form the drop down. 
May be you selected only iPhone from the drop down.